# Trying to understand "driver" program in java

Tags: java, arrays

I received this assignment and am not sure how to proceed.

I fulfilled the assignment of: asking 5 array inputs, the mean from 5 data input and to sort it from highest to lowest.

But I don't understand what (toString) is asking to do, how can it return a "string" data containing an ascending order of the array and the average at the same time?

Currently my program works, but I think I did something incorrectly with the toString method in the operator class (average).

Operator class, driver class, output window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijGSG.jpg

Assignment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DG5j0.jpg

Operator class (average)

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class average
{
    private int data[] = new int[5];
    private double mean = 0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 1;
    int index = 0;
    average()
    {

        for (int num : data)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter score for student " + i + " : ");
            i++;
            data[index] = keyboard.nextInt();
            index++;
        }

        toString();
    }
    public void calculateMean()
    {
        double total = 0;

        for (int num : data)
        {
            total = total + num;
        }

        mean = total / data.length;
        System.out.println("Average score is :" + mean);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        selectionSort();
        System.out.print("Data after selection sort (lowest to highest): ");
        index = 0;
        for (int num : data)
        {
            System.out.print(data[index] + " ");
            index++;
        }

        System.out.println("");

        calculateMean();

        String result = null;
        return result;
    }

    public void selectionSort()
    { 

        java.util.Arrays.sort(data);

    }
}
```

driver class (avgdr)

```
public class avgdr
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        average e1 = new average();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact language for the output you need.  Don't link to the assignment; links can break over time.

Comment: Please do look at the assignment carefully, it clearly states, `Create a class called Average`, but you are creating `average`. And moreover, the `toString ()` method, should return a `String` with elements in descending order and mean ( You can use a StringBuilder for this purpose ), whereas `toString ()` implementation done by you is returning `null`... Moreover, `Arrays.sort ( ... )` I guess uses `QuickSort` and not `SelectionSort`

Answer (score 1):

As it says, in the assignment, Your constructor should take the input from user and already do the calculation of calculating the mean.

After the mean is calculated, the toString method should simply the answer i.e. it should print the object status. [all the values in array and the mean value.]

```
public String toString() {
    return "Data after selection sort (lowest to highest): "
            + Arrays.toString(data) + "\nAverage score is: " + mean;
}
```

So all the calculation and method should be called from the constructor. And the toString method, you can call from the constructor or from the driver class. 
Its a usual practice to call it from the driver class as below - the driver class

```
public class avgdr {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        average e1 = new average();
        System.out.println(e1);
    }
}
```

On calling `System.out.println(e1);` automatically, the toString method of the class will be called and the returned string will be displayed on console.

and the constructor will look something like this -

```
average() {
    for (int num : data) {
        System.out.print("Enter score for student " + i + " : ");
        i++;
        data[index] = keyboard.nextInt();
        index++;
    }
    selectionSort();
    calculateMean();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I liked the answer till you wrote `System.out.println(e1.toString());` :-), since `System.out...` will implicitly call `toString () ` of `e1`, hence only `System.out.println(e1);`, this will do :-) +1 for the rest, I missed what you showed in your `toString ()` implementation, a call to `Arrays.toString ( data )` :-)

Comment: Thanks for the correction, actually, implicitly toString will be called. In the driver class, it should be called as below 
   `System.out.println(e1);`

Corrected it in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your toString need to return String which contain both array in ascending order and ,mean of it
For this you need two instance variable in your class which you already have 
1. Array : int data[] = new int[5]  
2. Mean :  double mean 
Just after taking Input from user call your selectionSort and calculateMean method, after that call toString method which do no further calculation just simply return the string you want

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class average {
private int data[] = new int[5];
private double mean = 0;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = 1;
int index = 0;
average()
{

    for (int num : data)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter score for student " + i + " : ");
        i++;
        data[index] = keyboard.nextInt();
        index++;
    }
    selectionSort();
    calculateMean();
    toString();
}
public void calculateMean()
{
    double total = 0;

    for (int num : data)
    {
        total = total + num;
    }

    mean = total / data.length;
    System.out.println("Average score is :" + mean);
}

public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("Sorted Data is: ");
    for (int num : data)
    {
        builder.append(data[index] + " ");
        index++;
    }
    builder.append(", Mean is: ").append(mean);
    return builder.toString();
}

public void selectionSort()
{ 
    java.util.Arrays.sort(data);

}
```

}

Comment: I don't think we're allowed to use stringbuilder yet

Comment: You can use System.Out.println() or simple String, as per your requirement. StringBuilder is used just for performance purpose

Comment: so I put the array into a string? How can I do that?

Comment: public String toString()
{
    String output = new String();
    output += "Sorted Data is: ";
    for (int num : data)
    {
        output += data[index] + " ";
        index++;
    }
    output += ", Mean is: " + mean;
    System.out.println(output);return output;
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
public String toString() //overriding toString() method here. This method belongs to Object Class.
    {
        selectionSort(); // calling selectionSort() here.
        System.out.print("Data after selection sort (lowest to highest): ");
        index = 0;
        for (int num : data)
        {
            System.out.print(data[index] + " ");
            index++;
        }

        System.out.println("");

        calculateMean();  //  Calling calculateMean() here.

        String result = null;
        return result;
     }
```

now you are calling this method inside Constructor

average()
    {

```
    for (int num : data)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter score for student " + i + " : ");
        i++;
        data[index] = keyboard.nextInt();
        index++;
    }

    toString(); //calling toString Method Here.
}
```

> **Flow Of Execution** :- Inside Constructor you are Calling `toString()` method which internally make a call to two functions A) `selectionSort();` and B) `selectionSort();`. And inside `main()` you making the instance of `average e1 = new average();` **average**. which calls the constructor So, Execution wil be like `Constuctor` > `toString()` > `calculateMean()` and `selectionSort()`.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, it seems you are not not suppose to call `toString ()` from anywhere in the code. Just make it return a `String` comprise of all elements in descending order and the `mean`. Moreover, the way you using a `Decorator`, `Scanner` in this case to take input from the user is slightly not right IMHO. Prefer Buffered streams for this purpose, and let them do the byte reading.

Here is the modified code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Average {

    private static final int TOTAL_SCORES = 5;

    private int [] data;
    private double mean;

    private BufferedReader inputStream;

    public Average () {
        data = new int [ TOTAL_SCORES ];
        try {
            inputStream = new BufferedReader ( 
                        new InputStreamReader ( System.in ) );
            for ( int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i ) {
                System.out.print ( "Enter Score Number " + ( i + 1 ) + ": " );
                data [ i ] = Integer.parseInt ( inputStream.readLine () );
            }
        } catch ( IOException ioex ) {
            ioex.printStackTrace ();
        }

        selectionSort ();
        calculateMean ();
    }

    private void selectionSort () {
        for ( int i = 0; i < ( data.length - 1 ); ++i ) {
            int max = i;
            for ( int j = ( i + 1 ); j < data.length; ++j ) {
                if ( data [ max ] < data [ j ] ) {
                    max = j;
                }
            }
            if ( max != i ) {
                int temp = data [ max ];
                data [ max ] = data [ i ];
                data [ i ] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    private void calculateMean () {
        double result = 0.0;
        for ( int number : data ) {
            result += number;
        }
        result /= data.length;

        mean = result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
        sb.append ( "Elements: \n" );
        for ( int number : data ) {
            sb.append ( number + "\n" );
        }
        sb.append ( "Mean: " + mean );

        return sb.toString ();
    }    

    private void display ( int [] data ) {
        System.out.println ( "Data in Array is: " );
        for ( int number : data ) {
            System.out.println ( number );
        }
    }

    public static void main ( String [] args ) {
        System.out.println ( new Average () );
    }
}
```